# How to read a media file from .py file using Django?

Tags: python, django, file-io

I can read `a.txt` file like this:

```
text = open('a.txt', 'rb').read()
```

But when I put the `a.txt` to the `media` folder, this doesn't work:

```
text = open('/media/a.txt', 'rb').read()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
IOError at /
[Errno 13] file not accessible: '/media/a.txt'
```

How can I read file from the `media` directory?

Comment: relative path issue? try `text = open('media/a.txt', 'rb').read()`

Answer (score 9):

To be more generic (and be sure that you use the media folder), you could change it to:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
text = open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'a.txt'), 'rb').read()
```

Answer (score 2):

The initial `/` means that it is an absolute path, accessed from the root of the filesystem. If you want to read a file from the project path then you will need to start the filename with the project path instead, or use `__file__` along with the functions in `os.path` to create an appropriate relative or absolute path.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot read static files from your application code in Google App Engine.  Files marked as static are served from different servers and not included with your application.  If your application needs to read them and they don't need to be served directly to users, don't mark them static.  If you need to both serve them directly to users and read them in python code, you need to include 2 copies in your project, one of which is marked as static and one which isn't.

Comment: I don't think the OP said anything about GAE.